# how can i combine these 3 matlab graphs to a single one?

Tags: matlab, plot

hello i have these three polar plots:

- polar(a,(V1).^(-1),'-r')
- polar(a,(V2).^(-1),'-g')
- polar(a,(V3).^(-1),'-m')

where V1,V2,V3 are matrices , how can i combine these 3 graphs to a single one (not like subplot , more like copyobj)?

Note: The axes remain the same in every graph.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hold on` as you would for any other types of graphs.

Example:

```
clear
clc
close all

figure;

theta1 = 0:0.01:2*pi;
rho1 = sin(2*theta1).*cos(2*theta1);

theta2 = 0:0.1:2*pi;
rho2 = cos(2*theta2).*cos(2*theta2);

theta3 = 0:0.1:2*pi;
rho3 = cos(2*theta2).*tan(2*theta2);

polar(theta1,rho1,'--r')

hold on

polar(theta2,rho2,'-b')
polar(theta3,rho3,'-g')
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hold on`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html). It will "hold" every plot you make and put the others on top. If you want to stop holdin, then `hold off`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys, solved it with:

```
 figure;
   b=polar(a,(V3).^(-1),'-m')
   hold on
   c=polar(a,(V2).^(-1),'-g')
   hold on
   a=polar(a,(V1).^(-1),'-r')
   hold off;
```

for some reason when i change the series that i write the polars (for example a,b,c) the method doesn't work... But now it's ok, so never mind :)